# Maclaurin series therom question of artan

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

find the Maclaurin series of $$\frac{1}{1+4x^2}$$ and $$\frac{1}{1+9x^2}$$ using $$\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Firstly I derived the formula they gave us, then substituted $x \rightarrow 9x$.
Is this the right approach?

Comment: Did you write the geometric series of $\dfrac{1}{1+4x^2}$.?

Comment: what do u mean?? @MyGlasses

Comment: Try substituting $u=2x$ for the first one (because then $u^2=4x^2$), and $u=3x$ for the second one.

Comment: @Théophile yes i did that and found that 1/3arctan (3x) = 1/1+9x^2 ..... so then i substiuted and found that 1/3arctan (3x) = sigma from n=1 is [(-1)^n 9^n x^(2n+1)] / 2n+1... using the thing thing they gave us in the question. so then i derived both and found 1/1+9x^2 to be sigm from n=1 is (-1)^n 9^n x^2n, which i think is the wrong answer

Comment: how can i check my answers????

Answer (score 1):

As you know that: 
$$ \arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \arctan (2x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$ 
Also, you have: 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[\arctan(x)\right] = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{d}{dx}\left[\arctan(2x)\right] = \frac{2}{1+4x^2} $$ 
Thus, 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\color{red}{\frac{1}{1+4x^2}} &= \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{d}{dx} \left[\color{white}{\frac{}{}}\arctan(2x)\color{white}{\frac{}{}}\right] = \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{d}{dx} \left[\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\,\frac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\,\right] \\[2mm] 
&= \frac{1}{2}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\,\frac{\left(\,(2x)^{2n+1}\,\right)'}{2n+1} \\[2mm] 
&= \frac{1}{2}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\,\frac{{2\,(2n+1)}\,(2x)^{2n}}{2n+1} \\[2mm] 
&= \color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\,(2x)^{2n}} 
\end{align} 
$$ 
And with similar analysis, you should get: 
$$ \frac{1}{1+9x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\,(3x)^{2n} $$

Comment: thank you.. but when u derive dont u add a +1 to the n, so now the series will start at n=1 not n=0... also so the answer for 9 would be (-1)^n(3x)^2n correct? also, how can i possibly check my answers?

Comment: Yes, you are right!! Try doing the same process for the other expression! =)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you take the derivative of a series of functions, shouldn't the uniform convergence be checked?

Comment: Yes! You need to justify why you can do what I did!

Comment: And how can you justify that? (I wouldn't know how to do it, this is why I'm asking).

Comment: @LuísaBorsato sooo if the question is 1/(4+x^2) i factored the 1/4 out and did 1/2arctan (x/2), which derived is 1/4+x^2,,, and got sum from n=1 of (-1)^n (1/4)^(n+1) x^2n... howveer when i used an online calculator to calcuate the maclaurian series of 1/(4+x^2), for some reason i got the same answer but they started at 0 and not 1.... do you know whhy plzzz help